# TLS1.3 Certificate Verification complete algorithm

Tags: algorithm, ssl, certificate, tls1.3, x509certificatevalidator

I would like to implement **TLS1.3 Certificate Verify** functionality (without external library, openssl etc.).

I am a bit confused about the documentation. According to it I am believing, that the algorithm, using **RSA-PSS-RSAE-SHA256** is the following:

1. Parsing and checking certificates received in the Certificate handshake is Ok. From here I can also get the public key (RSA n and e) for the Cerificate Verify
2. According to *RFC8446/4.4.3*, the content to sign consists of: 64 * 0x20 + "TLS 1.3, server CertificateVerify" + 0x00 + transcript-hash of messages (in our case, sha256 hash of concatenating all handshakes ClientHello...Certificate). I consider content to be message `M` in the followings.
3. **RSASSA-PPS** with **EMSA-PSS** (for the selected signature algorithm) is described in *RFC8017/8.1.2, 9.1.2*. There are two main steps: The signature has to be RSA-decrypted (*8.1.2*); EMSA-PSS verification has to be done (*9.1.2*):

   1. The firts one is rather trivial, resulting in Encoded Messaget `EM`
   2. hash (`H`), and `salt` can be extracted from that one. Details are in the RFC document
   3. Hash of M must be calculated: `mHash = sha256(M)`
   4. `H'` can be calculated by sha256 hash of `(8 * 0x00 + mHash + salt)`
4. If `H == H'`, then verification is successful.

At least this is how I interpret this. But it does not work:

1. I am almost sure, that my transcript-hash is good, I use the handshake concatenation in multiple positions in TLS communcation successfully, and calculating the hash of it is also not a big deal
2. So I am almost sure, that the content (prefixing the content hash with elements as seen above) is also Ok.
3. There might be a gap between RFC8446 and RFC8017, but I did not find any info on that. Maybe `M` of RSASSA-PPS is not the same as the content of TLS Certificate Verify content.
4. I could evaluate `H` and `salt` using the signature and the public key (there are good checking opportunities for this, so this is surely Ok in my case)

But as a result `H != H'`.

So I probably misunderstand something with this algorithm. Maybe the message `M` should be something different, or something else is missing. Is there any good description somewhere, which leads through this process step by step? Or a source which can be run part by part, so that I can check where my implementation deviates? (Pyhton or perl is preferred, but any major languages can be good)